# window.outerHeight using CSS

Tags: css

If I make the following code in CSS:

```
 html body {
     height: 100%
 }
```

`height` refers to window.innerHeight.

Is there a way to refers to window.outerHeight just using CSS?

Answer (score 0):

No, CSS is not meant to be able to resize the browser window. Use JavaScript for that. That said, a lot of users (like me) do not like it when someone resizes my browser window. I am of the opinion that your site should comply to my screen size, not my window should comply with your site.

**Update based on @RobW's Comment**

If you mean how do you control the area around the body of the page, you'll want to change the following:

```
body {
    margin: 100px; /* Something random to illustrate. This is area outside the body but, as with everything else, inside the browser window. */
    padding: 10px; /* This is more space, but also include the background image, which margin will not */
}
```

Comment: I can only assume by `window.outerHeight` he means the browser window. If he means the `outerHeight` of the body, than that is something different. I'll update it just in case he means that though

Comment: He probably wants to be able to set borders, paddings or margins in conjunction with `height:100%`, without showing scrollbars, without `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: I think the programmer should decide how the user views their site, not the other way around. It's viewer beware on the internet, your windows are not safe! And besides, with newer browsers you can't resize the current window anymore, it has to be a window that the website generated.

Comment: @MattK While I know I have the ability to change the browser window, I feel it is poor design and usability to resize the window. And I didn't know browsers were adding that restriction, but it is good to hear. Extra windows are fine to resize. My main window is absolutely not. The burden should be on the developer to maintain a site that is usable on different screens, not on the user to conform to the screen the designer wants.

Comment: @Ktash if you give someone a tool, they'll use it!

Comment: @MattK But if you're drawing a picture, a level isn't really a good tool ;)

Comment: @Ktash that's not a proper comparison, a better one would be... you have this wonderful window and you give everyone a window resizer, and then you get mad that they resized the window.

Comment: @MattK Haha, I kind of agree, but I think of the roles differently. I think of the web designer/programmer as the window installer and the user as the window re sizer. But I would say its more like you are running a museum, and every time someone walks through the door, you change their camera settings to be what you want it to be. Or that they must be a certain height. Or they can only hold a map a certain way. You are reaching into the users world and making them change something, instead of just letting them use your product.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. CSS cannot control the window properties.